# Add extra td to tr without respective th

Tags: html, css

I want to add extra td with my delete icon at the end to my tr without its respecting th column.

I want to adjust in such a way that I would not need any jquery and the table tag width is in percentage, so can not add one more th and make it invisible.

Please refer to below html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Col1
        </th>
        <th>
            Col 2
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td> 
            <!-- this is new column. -->
            Delete Link
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

p.s. I can not add position absolute css as it would not be possible to include in every screen resolution.

Comment: I for one don't understand the question. Your sample HTML indeed has an extra cell in the data row, but no corresponding header cell. So it appears you've already accomplished what you're asking how to do. Are you on about how your table renders? If the problem has to do with some jQuery code needing the header cell, perhaps you can add and remove the header cell immediately before and after using jQuery.

Comment: See I have 3 tables in one div. The width of div as well as table is fixed and in percentrage. Now I want to add one more column without affecting the width of table and without adding corresponding th

Comment: why not add an empty <th>? like <th></th>

Answer (score 1):

Did I understand your problem right? `colspan="2"` should be helping you.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Col1
    </th>
    <th colspan="2">
        Col 2
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
        2
    </td>
    <td> 
        <!-- this is new column. -->
        Delete Link
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe table needs to have its geometry to be consistent from top to bottom. The best answer i can give you is to hide the top row header column and make the others visible.

Comment: I want to adjust in such a way that I would not need any jquery and the table tag width is in percentage, so can not add one more th and make it invisible.